# Can't load a UIView with UICollectionVIewCell data

Tags: xml, swift, uiview, xml-parsing, uicollectionviewcell

I have searched everywhere to found a solution for this. Just trying my luck again by writing this question. I have a collectionViewCell in which I have parsed an XML URL data which includes a name and an ID. Now when I tap the cell, I want to load a UIView with an AVPlayer in it. To play the file, I have to use a different URL but with the id that I have parsed in that cell. Here is my `didSelectItem func`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let playerLauncher = PlayerLauncher()
        playerLauncher.showPlayer()
 }
```

This is my PlayerLauncher file:

```
import UIKit

import AVFoundation

class PlayerView: UIView {

    var item: Item?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        let id = item?.itemId

        if let url = URL(string: "http://xample.com/play.m3u?id=\(id)") {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            print(url)
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            playerLayer.frame = self.frame

            player.play()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class PlayerLauncher: NSObject {

        func showPlayer() {

            if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

                view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: keyWindow.frame.height - 50, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)

                let playerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)
                let playerView = PlayerView(frame: playerFrame)
                view.addSubview(playerView)

                keyWindow.addSubview(view)

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    view.frame = keyWindow.frame
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have set the item from my Item NSObject class but after selecting the cell the UIView loads fine but doesn't play the file and shows `id = nil`. How can I fix it?

**UPDATE: So I changed my code a bit and I can get id to print.**

Here are the changes I made in `didSelectItem` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let playerView = PlayerView()
        playerView.item = items?[indexPath.item]

        let playerLauncher = PlayerLauncher()
        playerLauncher.showPlayer()
 }
```

After this I changed some code in PlayerView and PlayerLauncher class:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayerView: UIView {

    var id: String?

    var item: Item? {
        didSet {
            id = item?.itemId
            print(id)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

    func startPlaying() {

        if let url = URL(string: "http://xample.com/play.m3u?id=\(id)") {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            print(url)
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            playerLayer.frame = self.frame

            player.play()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class PlayerLauncher: NSObject {

    func showPlayer() {

        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: keyWindow.frame.height - 50, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)

            let playerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)
            let playerView = PlayerView(frame: playerFrame)
            view.addSubview(playerView)

            keyWindow.addSubview(view)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                view.frame = keyWindow.frame
            }, completion: { (completeAnimation) in
                playerView.startPlaying()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can print the id from `didSet` but when in `startPlaying()` method it still shows `id = nil` when I select the item. How can I get the properties set in `didSet` in `init` or `startPlaying()` func?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it! Here are the changes I made in the code: 
in the `didSelectItem` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     if let item = items?[indexPath.item] {
        showPlayer(item: item)
     }
}

func showPlayer(item: Item) {

     let playerLauncher = PlayerLauncher()
     playerLauncher.item = item
     playerLauncher.showVideoPlayer()
}
```

In the PlayerView I edited `init` and `didSet` to:

```
var item = Item()

init(frame: CGRect, item: Item) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.item = item

    setupPlayerView()
    backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.3, alpha: 1)
}
```

In `setupPlayerView` method, I set up the `itemId` and finally in PlayerLauncher I just added:

```
var item = Item()
```

Hope it might be helpful for someone in future so posting the solution here. A big-2 thanks to @sCha for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to retrieve `Item` info when selecting a cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item: Item = itemList[indexPath.item]   // just for instance
    let playerLauncher = PlayerLauncher()
    playerLauncher.showPlayer(item)
}
```

and thus you'll need to change your `Player` something like followings:

```
class PlayerLauncher: NSObject {

    func showPlayer(item: Item) {

        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: keyWindow.frame.height - 50, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)

            let playerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)
            let playerView = PlayerView(frame: playerFrame)
            playerView.item = item // Here
            view.addSubview(playerView)

            keyWindow.addSubview(view)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                view.frame = keyWindow.frame
            }, completion: { _ in  
                playerView.startPlaying()  // And here
            })
        }
    }
}
```

and in the `PlayerView`:

```
class PlayerView: UIView {

    var item: Item?
    var player: AVPlayer?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func startPlaying() {
        let id = item?.itemId

        if let url = URL(string: "http://xample.com/play.m3u?id=\(id)") {
            self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            print(url)
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
            self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            playerLayer.frame = self.frame

            self.player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

try this and see what happens:

```
func startPlaying() {
    guard let id = id else { print("** id is nil"); return }  // here
    print("* item id = \(id)")         // and here

    if let url = URL(string: "http://xample.com/play.m3u?id=\(id)") {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        print(url)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        playerLayer.frame = self.frame

        player.play()
    }
}
```

**UPDATED #2:**

again, entire code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = items?[indexPath.item]
    let playerLauncher = PlayerLauncher()
    playerLauncher.showPlayer(item)
}
```

and:

```
class PlayerLauncher: NSObject {

    func showPlayer(item: Item) {

        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: keyWindow.frame.height - 50, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)

            let playerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)
            let playerView = PlayerView(frame: playerFrame)
            playerView.item = item // Here
            view.addSubview(playerView)

            keyWindow.addSubview(view)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                view.frame = keyWindow.frame
            }, completion: { _ in  
                playerView.startPlaying()  // And here
            })
        }
    }
}

class PlayerView: UIView {

    var id: String?
    var item: Item? {
        didSet {
            id = item?.itemId
            print(id)
        }
    }
    var player: AVPlayer?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func startPlaying() {
        guard let id = id else { print("** id is nil"); return }  // here
        print("* item id = \(id)")         // and here

        if let url = URL(string: "http://xample.com/play.m3u?id=\(id)") {
            self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            print(url)
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
            self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            playerLayer.frame = self.frame

            self.player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! It still shows id = nil. Do I need to make any changes in my PlayerView class? Because this is where I am calling the AVPlayer to play the link.

Comment: @Mohit Your `PlayerView` seems to start playing on initialization, sorry I glanced the code, so either you need to pass `item` on `init` or change the way it works. I'll add few codes in my answer.

Comment: @Mohit and one more thing. I believe your AVPlayer instance should be declared globally within the class. added in my answer as well.

Comment: I made all the changes but still, it shows id = nil. :(

Comment: @Mohit well the class looks ok to me, but I can't debug any deeper than this as I can't test it for myself. Please try to look into the `item` object in the `collectionView`'s delegate method if it actually exists. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I wish somehow I could fix it.

Comment: Hey! I've made some changes and updated my question. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: @Mohit Hi, why do you think your `id` is `nil` inside `startPlaying()` function? I don't see any `print` calls. Did you set breakpoints somewhere and inspect `id` property? Or do you think `id` is `nil` simply because player  doesn't work?

Comment: Hey! there is one print call in `didSet`. There I can print the specific IDs of the cell data. I think id is nil because I can't call the `id` property set in `didSet` in `startPlaying()` method. The `startPlaying()` grabs the id from `var id: String?` (Which is of course `nil`). What's the way to get the value from didSet to a function?

Comment: It prints `** id is nil`.
Hey! but I'm able to get the id printed in my link. But it doesn't play the file. These are the last few lines in console:

`playerasync_runOneCommand signalled err=-12785 (kCMBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (invalidated) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMedia_Sim/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2050.1.3/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c:1608
Task .<1> finished with error - code: -999
HTTP load failed (error code: 12 [1:12])
** id is nil`

Comment: @Mohit oh, your `PlayerLauncher` is creating another instance of `PlayerView` that does not have `Item` in it.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: By declaring AVPlayer globally?

Comment: @Mohit see my update #2, be sure to replace all codes and check what happens.

Comment: Still, `** id is nil`

Comment: Hey!  I actually fixed it. Getting the id in the URL now. But now I get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` error when loading AVPlayer. Can you please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042139/getting-error-thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-exc-i386-gpflt-when-loading-avplay

Answer (score 0):

Your item property in your PlayerView class is never set in your initializer. You either need to set it there or have any class that creates an instance of PlayerView set the item property. Otherwise it will always be nil.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you please tell me how can I create an Instance of it?