# Getting error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) when loading AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer, appdelegate

I am trying to load an AVPlayer when I select a collectionViewCell, Here is my code in `didSelectItem` :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let item = items?[indexPath.item] {
        showPlayer(item: item)
    }
}

func showPlayer(item: Item) {

    let playerLauncher = PlayerLauncher()
    playerLauncher.showVideoPlayer()

    let playerView = PlayerView()
    playerView.item = item
    playerView.setupPlayerView()
}
```

This is my PlayerLauncher file:

```
class PlayerView: UIView {

    var item: Item? {
        didSet {
            if let id = item?.itemId {
               itemId = id
            } 
        }
    }

    var itemId = String()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.3, alpha: 1)
    }

    var player: AVPlayer?

    func setupPlayerView() {

        let baseurl = "http://xample.com/play.m3u?id="

        let urlString = "\(baseurl)\(itemId)"
        print(urlString)
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)

            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            playerLayer.frame = self.frame

            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do{
                try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            } catch let err {
                print(err)
                return
            }

            player?.play()

            player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.status", options: .new, context: nil)
        }
    }
}

class PlayerLauncher: NSObject {

    func showVideoPlayer() {
        print("Showing the player...")

        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            view.frame = CGRect(x: keyWindow.frame.width - 10, y: keyWindow.frame.height - 10, width: 10, height: 10)

            let playerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)
            let playerView = PlayerView(frame: playerFrame)
            view.addSubview(playerView)

            keyWindow.addSubview(view)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                view.frame = keyWindow.frame
            }, completion: { (completedAnimation) in
                //later...

            })
        }
    }
}
```

So whenever I select the item, the player starts loading, console prints the URL (because I've added print statement there), This is what it prints:

```
http://xample.com/play.m3u?id=12345
(lldb)
```

and then It crashes and shows `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` error in AppDelegate. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I changed the `didSelectItem` func a bit. Here is the code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let item = items?[indexPath.item] {
        showPlayer(item: item)
    }
}

func showPlayer(item: Item) {
    let playerLauncher = PlayerLauncher()
    playerLauncher.showPlayer(item: item)
}
```

I changed the `init` method in `PlayerView` to this:

```
var item: Item? {
    didSet {
        if let id = item?.itemId {
            itemId = id
        }
    }
}

init(frame: CGRect, item: Item) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.item = item

    setupPlayerView()
    setupContainerView()
    backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.3, alpha: 1)
}
```

And the required changes in `PlayerLauncher`:

```
let playerView = PlayerView(frame: playerFrame, item: item)
view.addSubview(playerView)
```

I put a break on `let playerView` line and I can see the item Id passed there. But it is not getting passed to the urlString in `PlayerView` class. Hence, ID is still `" "`.

Comment: Bro, you are still making the same mistake. I'm not sure how to make you understand this... but I'll try one more time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've made a guide that hopefully shows what you've been misunderstanding.

I apologize to other readers for not using MARKDOWN text format, but please do consider this as my upmost attempt for the original poster. We've already went through sufficient discussions in the previous post.

[image]

So, how do you fix this?
I guess there's nothing good to give you codes directly, please try to fix the code based on this information.

And if you have more questions, I'll try my best to help you :)

Comment: Hey! I finally fixed it! Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

It appears

```
class PlayerLauncher: NSObject
```

Has no way to reference

```
let playerView = PlayerView()
```

Try to define those outside the function scope so they can be changed by the function and referenced outside the function.

Comment: I removed the `setupPlayer()` func and wrote the AVPlayer code in `override init`. It doesn't crash now but the `itemId` is empty now and it doesn't play anything.

Comment: Just make another var that you pass to whatever needs it after/during init